# Applying annotationProcessor in Gradle version 4.6

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processor

I am having a hard time building my project. I am using dagger 2, and therefore I need to use annotation processor. I use gradle wrapper version 4.6 with the following build:

```
plugins {
  id "java"
  id "idea"
}

group 'xyz.blackmonster'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
  dropwizardVersion = "1.3.0"
  mysqlConnectorVersion = "8.0.9-rc"
  daggerVersion = "2.15"
  mockitoVersion = "2.16.0"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-core', version: dropwizardVersion
  compile group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-jdbi3', version: dropwizardVersion
  compile group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-auth', version: dropwizardVersion
  compile group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-metrics-graphite', version: dropwizardVersion
  compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: mysqlConnectorVersion
  annotationProcessor group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: daggerVersion
  implementation group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: daggerVersion
  testCompile group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-testing', version: dropwizardVersion
  testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion
}
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html), they have added annotation processor support out of the box in 4.6 (no need to use any plugins). I am trying to use the same approach. Now, since I do not set the annotationProcessorPath, it should automatically use the build path, since the value by default is *null* - [annotationProcessorPath documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html). But it seems this is not the case. My Dagger classes are being generated properly in *build/classes/java/main*, but they are not being picked up. For building the classes, I have Java 8 installed locally (console output):

```
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

I am running gradle with the following command: `./gradlew clean build`
To prove I am using the right version, I ran the command: `./gradlew -version` and got this console output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation 25.162-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64
```

So, when running the build `./gradlew build`, I get the following output:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
.../src/main/java/xyz/blackmonster/resume/app/ResumeApplication.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.DaggerBeanComponent;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class DaggerBeanComponent
  location: package xyz.blackmonster.resume.config
1 error
```

Here is the Application file:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.resume.app;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilderSpec;
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthDynamicFeature;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthValueFactoryProvider;
import io.dropwizard.auth.CachingAuthenticator;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentialAuthFilter;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentials;
import io.dropwizard.jdbi3.JdbiFactory;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.bean.BeanComponent;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.bean.BeanModule;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.DaggerBeanComponent;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.ResumeConfiguration;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.security.auth.ResumeAuthorizer;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.security.model.User;

public class ResumeApplication extends Application<ResumeConfiguration> {

    private static final String REALM = "resume";
    private static final String MYSQL = "mysql";

    private BeanComponent beanComponent;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ResumeApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ResumeConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        final JdbiFactory factory = new JdbiFactory();
        final Jdbi jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), MYSQL);

        beanComponent = DaggerBeanComponent.builder().beanModule(new BeanModule(jdbi)).build();

        environment.jersey().register(beanComponent.getAchievementControler());

        CachingAuthenticator<BasicCredentials, User> cachingAuthenticator =
            new CachingAuthenticator<>(
                environment.metrics(), 
                beanComponent.getResumeAuthenticator(), 
                CacheBuilderSpec.parse(configuration.getAuthenticationCachePolicy()));

        environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(
            new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                .setAuthenticator(cachingAuthenticator)
                .setAuthorizer(new ResumeAuthorizer())
                .setRealm(REALM)
                .buildAuthFilter()));
        environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
    }
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I can see the dagger files being generated in *xyz.blackmonster.resume.config*. Gradle would need to use then those compiled files, but does not "find" those files for some reason. I would appreciate any valuable input.

Comment: Which processor did you try?

Comment: @RomanC the build in one in gradle 4.6. They mentioned that this is now a new feature in the latest version, I looked it up in the release notes and attached the link up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed out my problem. In regards to gradle, everything is perfect. The problem was java related. I moved my Dagger-related classes into another package. And because of that I had the wrong (old) import added to the Application class. So naturally, when I was building the project, I had the wrong import and the class could not be found.

The new Application file looks now like this:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.resume.app;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilderSpec;
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthDynamicFeature;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthValueFactoryProvider;
import io.dropwizard.auth.CachingAuthenticator;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentialAuthFilter;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentials;
import io.dropwizard.jdbi3.JdbiFactory;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.bean.BeanComponent;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.bean.BeanModule;
// wrong import was used here
// before I had import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.DaggerBeanComponent
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.bean.DaggerBeanComponent;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.config.ResumeConfiguration;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.security.auth.ResumeAuthorizer;
import xyz.blackmonster.resume.security.model.User;

public class ResumeApplication extends Application<ResumeConfiguration> {

    private static final String REALM = "resume";
    private static final String MYSQL = "mysql";

    private BeanComponent beanComponent;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ResumeApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ResumeConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        final JdbiFactory factory = new JdbiFactory();
        final Jdbi jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), MYSQL);

        beanComponent = DaggerBeanComponent.builder().beanModule(new BeanModule(jdbi)).build();

        environment.jersey().register(beanComponent.getAchievementControler());

        CachingAuthenticator<BasicCredentials, User> cachingAuthenticator =
            new CachingAuthenticator<>(
                environment.metrics(), 
                beanComponent.getResumeAuthenticator(), 
                CacheBuilderSpec.parse(configuration.getAuthenticationCachePolicy()));

        environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(
            new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                .setAuthenticator(cachingAuthenticator)
                .setAuthorizer(new ResumeAuthorizer())
                .setRealm(REALM)
                .buildAuthFilter()));
        environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
    }
}
```